# scala2.10.4 with gradle report mismatch

Tags: scala, gradle

I have a scenario when using gradle build is causing a type mismatch that I cannot seem to resolve. but using maven build is success

```
if (profileSet.isDefined) {
    val profileFilterPredicate = FilterApi.userDefined(
        FilterApi.intColumn(PROFILE_ID_COLUMN_NAME),
        new TvdProfileIdFilterInPredicate(profileSet.get))
      ParquetInputFormat.setFilterPredicate(job.getConfiguration, profileFilterPredicate)
    }   
   public static <T extends Comparable<T>, U extends UserDefinedPredicate<T> & Serializable>
    UserDefined<T, U> userDefined(Column<T> column, U udp) {
    return new UserDefinedByInstance<T, U>(column, udp);
  }
```

**Error:**

```
 found   : com.grdsum.spark.tvd.TvdProfileIdFilterInPredicate
 required: Class[?]
        new TvdProfileIdFilterInPredicate(profileSet.get))
        ^
```

Comment: Is `TvdProfileIdFilterInPredicate` actually `Serializable`?

Comment: yes. `class TvdProfileIdFilterInPredicate(profiles: Set[Integer]) extends UserDefinedPredicate[Integer] with Serializable `